# Open Variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

I need a help. I need a variable that is available for every function in my app

```
    @interface A()
    @property (assign) CGFloat x;
    @end

    @implementation
    @synthesize x = _x;

    -(void)DidLoad
    { ...
     self.x = 1.0; }

    -function1
    { CGFloat y;
      y = x;
      NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%f", y];
      NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

---

But "y" is empty variable ! Could you help a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

In function1 you should use:

```
y = self.x;

y = _x; //this should work too, but it's not recommended to access the variable that way.
```

Comment: Why would you say that using the iVar is not recommended? It's totally safe as far as memory management and foregoes the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Oh, i did a mistake. I wrote y = self.x; and "y" is still empty

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Using iVars in this context is safe (where it and the property are the same), it's situations where the property may have custom code in it that it becomes a problem - getting/setting the iVar won't call the code. I find it good practise to always use the property so it becomes habit.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I say it's not recommended because that way you are not accessing the setter/getter method. In this case it may be safe, but I find it a good practice to call the getters and setters.